# Maintaining data structure with two operations

Tags: data-structures

I was trying to implement data structure over set of rectangles that can perform two types of operations.

1. Update operation, add new rectangle with sides parallel to x and y axis and positive coordinates to the set.
2. Query operation, for some rectangle check if there is some rectangle intersecting with this rectangle.

I don't have big knowledge of data structures so I was thinking if you could give me some hints how to start approach this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be non-trivial even in the one dimensional case

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) (described in detail [here](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/SI-LS/papers/Gut84.pdf)) or a similar tree data structure for [spatial indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index).